# Reproducing Github Webhook -> Jenkins request on Postman fails : signature didn't match to calculated

Tags: git, github, jenkins, git-webhooks, jenkins-github-plugin

Github Webhook (currently disabled) is connected to Jenkins Server.
One of the successful requests is pull request create.

I am trying to reproduce the same request and see if it succeeds by trying the same request (URL, headers and payload) on Postman. But it fails giving the error

```
Error 400 Provided signature [<signature>] did not match to calculated
```

Context: In order to find a way to discover a branch in Jenkins, I am trying to see if I can use HTTP request to forward the request from Lambda to Jenkins (currently my Github webhook points to a Lambda function which needs to somehow notify Jenkins that a new PR is created so branch re-indexing is required so that the new PR branch is discovered allowing it to be triggered later)

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me after internet domain change (e.g. from `https://jenkins.mydomain.com:<PORT>` to `https://jenkins.mydomain.org:<PORT>`) in the `Payload URL` field on Github's `Webhooks` > `Manage webhook` page.

A **workaround** (which is at least 5 years old, see my [source](https://github.com/dlang/ci/issues/27#issuecomment-284167900)) is to use `Settings` > `Content type` drop-down menu to switch the **`content-type`** from the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to **`application/json`**.